# Android Inject Dependency (Dagger 2) Inside Fragment Using @ContributesAndroidInjector

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm using [Dagger 2](https://github.com/google/dagger) for dependency injection in my project

The problem is when I'm trying to inject a `ViewPageAdapter` inside the fragment class which depend on `FragmentManager` like bellow:

```
@Inject
lateinit var mainTripsFragmentAdapter: MainTripsFragmentAdapter
```

I get the following build error:

> error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
>   public abstract interface AppComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector {
>                   ^
>         android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager is injected at
>             com.example.presenters.main.trips.MainTripsFragmentAdapter.(fragmentManager, …)
>         com.example.presenters.main.trips.MainTripsFragmentAdapter is injected at
>             com.example.presenters.main.trips.MainTripsFragment.mainTripsFragmentAdapter
>         com.example.presenters.main.trips.MainTripsFragment is injected at
>             com.example.presenters.main.MainActivity.tripsFragment
>         com.example.presenters.main.MainActivity is injected at
>             dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
>     A binding with matching key exists in component: com.example.di.FragmentBuilder_BindMainTripsFragment$app_debug.MainTripsFragmentSubcomponent

I've researched for 3 days and I've read many articles but I couldn't figure out where the problem is!
I'll post the related code, sorry if it's too long

The `Fragment` which needs `PagerAdapter`:

```
class MainTripsFragment @Inject constructor() : BaseFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mainTripsFragmentAdapter: MainTripsFragmentAdapter

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        pager.adapter = mainTripsFragmentAdapter
    }
}
```

BaseFragment:

```
abstract class BaseFragment : DaggerFragment() {

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this)
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(getLayout(), container, false)

    abstract fun getLayout(): Int
}
```

Here is the `FragmentPagerAdapter`:

```
class MainTripsFragmentAdapter @Inject constructor(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    private val mainCurrentTripsFragment: MainCurrentTripsFragment,
    private val mainHistoryTripsFragment: MainHistoryTripsFragment
) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int) = when (position) {
        0 -> mainCurrentTripsFragment
        1 -> mainHistoryTripsFragment
        else -> mainCurrentTripsFragment
    }

    override fun getCount() = 2
}
```

And here is DI related classes:

AppComponent:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [
    AndroidInjectionModule::class,
    ActivityBuilder::class,
    FragmentBuilder::class
])

interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<DaggerApplication> {

    fun inject(app: App)

    override fun inject(instance: DaggerApplication)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(app: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

FragmentBuilder:

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    internal abstract fun bindMainHomeFragment(): MainHomeFragment

    @Module
    internal interface MainTripsFragmentModule {

        @Binds
        fun bindMainTripsFragment(fragment: MainTripsFragment): Fragment
    }

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FragmentModule::class, MainTripsFragmentModule::class])
    internal abstract fun bindMainTripsFragment(): MainTripsFragment

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    internal abstract fun bindMainCurrentTripsFragment(): MainCurrentTripsFragment
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    internal abstract fun bindMainHistoryTripsFragment(): MainHistoryTripsFragment
}
```

FragmentModule:

```
@Module
class FragmentModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideFragmentManager(fragment: Fragment) = fragment.childFragmentManager
}
```

ActivityBuilder:

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    internal abstract fun contributeMainActivity(): MainActivity
}
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

     @Inject
     lateinit var tripsFragment: MainTripsFragment

     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

         showFragment(tripsFragment)
     }

     private fun showFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
         supportFragmentManager
                 .beginTransaction()
                 .replace(R.id.layout_container, fragment)
                 .commit()
     }
 }
```

BaseActivity:

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), HasSupportFragmentInjector {

@Inject
lateinit var fragmentInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
    override fun supportFragmentInjector() = fragmentInjector
}
```

Application Class:

```
class App : Application(), HasActivityInjector {
    @Inject
    lateinit var activityInjector: DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity>

    override fun activityInjector(): AndroidInjector<Activity> = activityInjector

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                .application(this)
                .build()
                .apply {
                    inject(this@App)
                }

    }
}
```

One point is that if I `@Inject` PagerAdapter Inside My Activity(I also should add a module for it) it works fine.
Which part is Implemented wrong?

Comment: I use dagger 2 in old fashioned way, but where did you provide MainTripsFragmentAdapter in your module?

Comment: If you look at the error, you can see towards the bottom that the issue is that you try to inject `tripsFragment` in your `MainActivity`. This is the wrong scope and your mainActivity component has no access to your FragmentSubComponents graph (which the _binding with matching key exists in component_ tries to tell you)

Comment: @Debanjan I have not provided it anywhere but I injected the constructor so I consider that dagger will fulfill it's dependencies

Comment: @DavidMedenjak As I'm beginner with dagger2 and DI I can't really understand how scopes are related to each other.
Can you tell if it is a way to fix it or I'm doing all wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of problems here:

```
class MainTripsFragmentAdapter @Inject constructor(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    private val mainCurrentTripsFragment: MainCurrentTripsFragment,
    private val mainHistoryTripsFragment: MainHistoryTripsFragment
) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {

    override fun getItem(position: Int) = when (position) { 
        0 -> mainCurrentTripsFragment  //no!!
        1 -> mainHistoryTripsFragment
        else -> mainCurrentTripsFragment
    }

    override fun getCount() = 2
}
```

`getItem` in the `PagerAdapter` means "create item". When you use a `PagerAdapter` you delegate *creation* of Fragments to the adapter. You shouldn't write code to cache and store the Fragments, this is the job of the `FragmentManager`.

Instead your `FragmentAdapter` should look something like this:

```
    override fun getItem(position: Int) = when (position) { 
        0 -> MainCurrentTripsFragment.instantiate()
        1 -> MainHistoryTripsFragment.instantiate()
        else -> MainCurrentTripsFragment.instantiate()
    }
```

Where the `instantiate` method is declared inside a companion object inside your Fragments:

```
class MainCurrentTripsFragment: Fragment() {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun instantiate(args: Bundle?) {
            val frag = MainCurrentTripsFragment()
            frag.arguments = args
        }
    }
}
```

That is the standard idiom for using a `PagerAdapter` with Fragments in Android. You shouldn't provide PagerAdapters or Fragments as dependencies in your object graph. In fact, many Android classes controlled by the OS like `FragmentManager`, `Activity`, `Fragment`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `Service` are not good candidates for becoming dependencies in your object graph using Dagger 2.

A common error when starting to use Dagger 2 is try and inject *everything*, as if newing up anything manually is wrong. This is just not possible in Android.

Please take the Fragments, the FragmentManager, the PagerAdapter etc out of your modules. Don't try to provide these or bind these using Dagger 2. Then use Dagger 2 to inject domain layer or data layer objects like repositories, Retrofit services etc. If you get stuck, you can always post another question.

And have a look at the offical [Google Android Architecture blueprints](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp-dagger/). Your solution should, ideally, look something like them.

Comment: Although it wasn't the direct answer for the question but I've learned many things by your answer
so you generally mean that android things shouldn't provide by dagger and we should simply make new instance of them anywhere we needed?

Comment: @Mosius I realise it's not a complete answer but part of the reason you have got into so much difficulty is from trying to make everything a dependency to be injected using Dagger 2. FragmentManager doesn't need to be a dependency, just call `getFragmentManager`. Same thing with the `PagerAdapter`, you can just new it up in `onCreate`

Comment: If you look at the sample project you will get a good idea of what you should and shouldn't inject as dependencies using Dagger 2